# Powershell SQLCMD not recognizing inputfile - passing files obtained via Get-ChildItem to external programs by path

Tags: powershell, scripting, filepath, get-childitem

I have this code, which gets all *.sql files in the current directory and for every child directory runs them on a specified `$server` and `$database`:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($d in $dirs)
{    
    $Result = Get-ChildItem ./ -Filter *.sql
    Foreach($item in $Result)
    {
        echo $item.Name
        sqlcmd /S $server /d $database -E -i $item
    }
}
```

This code works just fine but it is just a stepping stone towards a script that should get all the *.sql files in the *child directories* and run them on the server.

This code is the same with the difference of `./` being replaced by `$d` and it doesn't work:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($d in $dirs)
{
    $Result = Get-ChildItem $d -Filter *.sql
    Foreach($item in $Result)
    {
        echo $item.Name
        sqlcmd /S $server /d $database -E -i $item
    }
}
```

Instead I get the error:
`SQLCMD.EXE : Sqlcmd: 'INSERT Script1.sql': Invalid filename.
At E:\dir\Run all SQL in dir.ps1:23 char:12
+         sqlcmd <<<<  /S $server /d $database -E -i $item
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: 'INSERT...valid filename.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`

As far as I could tell from testing `$item` is the same in both cases and `$Result` looks the same.

I have no idea why the second version does not work. I want the script to iterate over all child directories of the current directory it is located in, get all *.sql files in each one, print the name of the file and run it against the set `$server` and `$database`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$item` is a `[FileInfo]` object.

Change to `$item.FullName`, which will contain the full file path.

I assume the first version works because the file is in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you and yes.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [gms0ulman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49514482/45375):

In ***Windows PowerShell*** (as opposed to [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)), **`[System.IO.FileInfo]` and `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances output by `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item`** ***situationally*<sup>[1]</sup> stringify to the *file name only* (`.Name`)** rather than the *full path* (`.FullName`), which, in combination with PowerShell's parameter binding, **can lead to subtle bugs**:

<sup>Note: I use *file name* loosely here to refer to both a file's name and a directory's name; to put it differently: a file-system item's name.</sup>

- Passing such an instance to an *external program*, as in your case, then passes the *file name only*, because **all arguments to external programs are *implicitly stringified***.

  - Using `.FullName` in this case is indeed the correct solution.
- More surprisingly, however, **the problem also affects *cmdlet* / function calls**:

  - In your code, the `$d` in `Get-ChildItem $d` is *also* passed as a *string* and therefore as a file name only, because - unfortunately - **the `-Path` parameter binds its *direct* arguments as *strings*** instead of recognizing `[System.IO.FileInfo]` / `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances as such; by contrast, passing such instances via the *pipeline* works correctly.
  - Thus, even though `$d` unambiguously identifies a given directory, only its *name* is passed, which at best *happens* to work, at worst *targets a different directory*, and otherwise *fails*.

    - Using `.FullName` here too bypasses the problem: `Get-ChildItem $d.FullName`
  - This problem has been [reported in GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057) and I encourage anyone interested in a fix to make their voice heard there.
    A note on backward compatiblity: changing how `[System.IO.FileInfo]` and `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` stringify (stringifying as their `.FullName` property value) is probably too breaking a change, but changing the parameter binding as described in the linked GitHub issue is well worth considering, given that the current behavior is essentially broken.

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details on the conditions under which this name-only stringification occurs in Windows PowerShell.</sup>