# PowerShell script not zipping correct files

Tags: powershell, zip, target, 7zip, get-childitem

```
 Function Zip
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$zipFile
        ,
        [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )
    $CurDir = Get-Location
    Set-Location "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
    .\7z.exe A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
    Set-Location $CurDir
}
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "60"
$TargetFolder = "C:\users\Admin\Downloads\*.*"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
$Files
Zip C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST.zip $Files
```

I am testing out this script I found online. My problem is that instead of zipping the files in the target folder, it is copying and zipping the contents of the 7-zip program file folder. What could cause this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you find the script? When file objects are forced to strings they just become the file names... not the full path. I think you need to process each file 1 by 1. Also you could remove `Out-Null` to help get yourself more information as to what is happening.

Comment: @Matt: _Here_ they indeed stringify to file names only, which is the problem, but whether they stringify to mere file names or full paths _generally depends on the specifics of the `Get-ChildItem` call_, (very) unfortunately - I've tried to summarize the rules in my answer.

Comment: I saw that. Colour me impressed. It annoys me that it is inconsistent. I'm just used to using fullnames now

Comment: @Matt: Yes, it's very unfortunate behavior that makes for insidious bugs. I'm glad the problem no longer occurs in PS Core (and let's hope that the change, which was technically a breaking one, was intentional or will at least be retained).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Pass the files as *full paths*** to the `Zip` function, using their **`.FullName` property** (PSv3+ syntax):

```
Zip C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\TEST.zip $Files.FullName
```

---

The problem is that, **in *Windows PowerShell*, the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances returned by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) *situationally*<sup>[1]</sup> stringify to their *file names only***, which is what happened in your case, so your `Zip` function then interpreted the `$toBeZipped` values as *relative to the current location*, which is `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` at that point.

That said, it's **better not to use `Set-Location` in your function altogether**, so that in the event that you *do* want to pass actual *relative* paths, they are correctly interpreted as relative to the *current* location:

```
Function Zip {
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] # make sure a value is passed          
        [string]$zipFile
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] # make sure a value is passed
        [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )
    # Don't change the location, use & to invoke 7z by its full path.
    $null = & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped
    # You may want to add error handling here.
}
```

---

[1] ***When* `Get-ChildItem` output stringifies to file *names* only:**

Note:

- **If `Get-ChildItem` output is to be passed to *other file-processing cmdlets***, say [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item), **the problem can be *bypassed* by providing input to them *via the pipeline***, which implicitly binds to the target cmdlet's `-LiteralPath` parameter by full path - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69921220/45375) for more information.
- **The related [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) cmdlet output *always* stringifies to the full path,** fortunately.
- **In [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v6.1+, `Get-ChildItem` too *always* stringifies to the full path**, fortunately.

The following therefore **only applies to `Get-ChildItem` in *Windows PowerShell***:

The problem is twofold:

- Even PowerShell's built-in cmdlets bind file / directory *arguments* (parameter values - as opposed to input via the *pipeline*) not as *objects*, but as *strings* (changing this behavior is being discussed in [GitHub issue #6057](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6057)).
- Therefore, for robust argument-passing, you need to ensure that your `Get-ChildItem` output consistently stringifies to *full paths*, which `Get-ChildItem` does *not* guarantee - and it's easy to forget when *name-only* stringification occurs or even that you need to pay attention to it at all.

**Always passing the `.FullName` property values instead is the simplest workaround** or, for reliable operation with *any* PowerShell provider, not just the filesystem, **`.PSPath`**.

**`[System.IO.FileInfo]` and `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances output by a `Get-ChildItem` command stringify to their file *names* only, *if and only if***:

- If **one or more *literal directory paths*** are passed to `-LiteralPath` or `-Path` (possibly as the 1st positional argument) *or* ***no path at all*** is passed (target the current location); that is, if the *contents* of directories are enumerated.
- ***and* does not *also* use the `-Include` / `-Exclude` parameters** (whether `-Filter` is used  makes *no* difference).
- By contrast, whether or not the following are also present makes *no* difference:

  - `-Filter` (optionally as the *2nd* positional argument, but note that specifying a wildcard expression such as `*.txt` as the *1st* (and possibly only) positional argument binds to the `-Path` parameter)
  - `-Recurse` (by *itself*, but note that it is often combined with `-Include` / `-Exclude`)

**Example commands:**

```
# NAME-ONLY stringification:

Get-ChildItem | % ToString # no target path

Get-ChildItem . | % ToString # path is literal dir.

Get-ChildItem . *.txt | % ToString  # path is literal dir., combined with -Filter

# FULL PATH stringification:

Get-ChildItem foo* | % ToString # non-literal path (wildcard)

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.txt | % ToString # use of -Include

Get-ChildItem file.txt | % ToString # *file* path
```

Comment: Extensive explanation. I am surprised that `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.txt | % ToString` produces the current directory files, but `Get-ChildItem -Include *.txt | % ToString` does not.

Comment: @lit: That is indeed another pitfall - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304

Answer (score 1):

If you (temporarily) disable the `|Out-Null` you'll see what error msg pass along.
$Files contains objects not just an array of file names.

By default powershell tries to stringify this using the `Name` property which doesn't contain the path - so 7zip can't find the files as you also change the path to the 7zip folder (and -recurse collecting $files)

So change the line

```
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
```

and append

```
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

A slightly reformatted verson ofyour source:

```
Function Zip{
    Param (
        [string]$zipFile,
        [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
}
$Days = "60"
$LastWrite = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$Days)

$TargetFolder = "$($ENV:USERPROFILE)\Downloads\*"

$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse | 
   Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite} | 
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$Files
Zip "$($ENV:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\TEST.zip" $Files
```

Comment: Ok. It worked. However if I try it again, and there isn't any folders that meet the criteria to be zipped, it will zip the contents of the 7zip program. Is there anyway to prevent that?

Comment: Sorry I can't follow I just tested my posted version with the suggest edits and it run's here without flaw. I agree with mklement0 that it's better **NOT** to change the path to 7zip folder to avid zipping that folder as suggested by @mklement0

Comment: Yes, the posted version works. However, lets say I run this in a file that doesn't have any files to be zipped, what will happen is that all of the contents of the 7-zip program are copied into the ZIP folder.

Comment: Make the params mandatory `Param (
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$zipFile,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )`

Comment: @LotPings: _Here_ the objects indeed stringify to file names only, which is the problem, but whether they stringify to mere file names (`.Name`) or full paths (`.FullName`) _generally depends on the specifics of the `Get-ChildItem` call_, (very) unfortunately - I've tried to summarize the rules in my answer.