# Get-ChildItem and wildcards and filtering

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

I have two different ways of getting files with a wildcard pattern:

```
Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory/*.csv"
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory" -Filter *.csv
```

I prefer to use the latter instead of the former because the former (`Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory/*.csv"`) has, on occasion, given me a permission denied error.

They both appear to return the same results, but when I try to compress the resulting files with this command:

```
Compress-Archive -Update -Path $CsvFiles -DestinationPath C:\Users\admin\Downloads\foo.zip
```

the former succeeds while the latter fails with the following error:

```
Compress-Archive : The path 'rgb dev automation store a_1-1_2194_20181120.csv'
either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Compress-Archive -Update -Path $CsvFiles -DestinationPath C:\Users\ad ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (rgb dev automat...94_20181120.csv:String) [Compress-Archive], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Compress-Archive
```

So what's the difference between these two ways of getting a listing of files using wildcards?  Or perhaps asked another way, why does using `-Filter *.csv` cause the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet to fail?

[image]

Comment: there may be an odd character in the file name that is giving you that error. have you tried `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, i have tried LiteralPath and the results are the same

Comment: well, that is one easy fix that aint a fix. [*sigh ...*] ///// what happens if you leave off the entirely unneeded quotes in this line `Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory" -Filter *.csv`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I've tried that too and nothing changes

Comment: ouch! i am out of ideas ... i'll go back to lurking. good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The reason you're seeing different behavior is the - obscurely situational - stringification behavior of the objects output by `Get-ChildItem`:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) details when `Get-ChildItem` output happens to stringify to a *mere filename* vs. a *full path*, and it so happens that `Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory" -Filter *.csv` stringifies to mere filenames.

The **workaround** is to explicitly stringify the objects as their *full paths* via their `FullName` property (PSv3+ syntax):

```
$CsvFiles = (Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory" -Filter *.csv).FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from a shell with the location of the folder where the CSV files are located then this will work. What you are doing by passing the `$CsvFiles` variable into `Compress-Archive` is trying to run against the file name in the current context. To fix this pass the full path `$CsvFiles.FullName`:

```
$Csvfiles = (Get-Childitem $ActivityLogDirectory -Filter *.csv)
Compress-Archive -Update -Path $Csvfiles.fullname -DestinationPath C:\Users\admin\Downloads\foo.zip
```

Comment: Your answer gets `Compress-Archive` to work, but I'd still like to know what the difference is between the two ways of using `Get-ChildItem` with wildcards

Comment: I am not entirely sure both methods work for me. Can you see what the results are for `$CsvFiles.psstandardmembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames` where `$CsvFiles` is populated using `Get-ChildItem "$ActivityLogDirectory" -Filter *.csv` ?

Comment: Using either way of calling `Get-ChildItem` and then calling `$CsvFiles.psstandardmembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames` returns the same results `LastWriteTime`, `Length` and `Name`

Comment: Strange, i am getting the same results now: `What if: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
C:\test\New Microsoft Excel Workshee.csv
C:\test\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet (2).csv".` When you create the variable with your first method, the full path is being passed to `Compress-Archive` with the second, it is only passing the name `Compress-Archive : The path 'New Microsoft Excel Workshee.csv' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path`