# Grep | sed -i equivalent for Windows

Tags: bash, powershell

I'm trying to replicate this command into PowerShell:

```
grep -lR 'Find' ./src | while read filename; do sed -i".bak" 's/Find/Replace/g' "$filename"; done
```

What I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem "src" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object { $f = $_; (Get-Content $f) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Find", "Replace" } | Set-Content "$f.tmp"; Move-Item "$f.tmp" $f -Force }
```

I'm getting an error saying `"filename.tmp" does not exist`. I thought the above would create the file while parsing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you've fallen victim to Windows PowerShell's inconsistent stringification of the `System.IO.FileInfo` instances output by `Get-ChildItem` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

The workaround is to use explicit stringification via the `.FullName` property, which explicitly returns an item's full path.

Applied to your command, alongside some optimizations:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse src | ForEach-Object { 
   $f = $_.FullName  # !! Explicitly retrieve the full path
   (Get-Content $f -Raw) -creplace 'Find', 'Replace' | 
     Set-Content -NoNewline "$f.tmp"
   Move-Item "$f.tmp" $f -Force
}
```

- `Get-Content -Raw` reads the entire file into memory as a single string, which is more efficient.
- `-creplace` (which performs case-*sensitive* replacement, as `sed` would by default) is directly applied to the resulting multiline string and replaces all occurrences.
- `-NoNewline` (PSv5+) ensures that `Set-Content` doesn't add an *additional* trailing newline to the multiline string being saved (the same applies to `Out-File` / `>`).
- Note: Given that `Get-Content -Raw` reads the entire file up front, you could even write the modified content back to the very same file, without requiring an intermediate temporary file and a subsequent `Move-Item` call; that said, doing so bears a slight risk of data loss, if the process of writing back to the same file is interrupted.

  - Also, while your `sed` call retains the original file with extension `.bak`, your PowerShell command does not.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Milk; my pleasure. Good point re `-NoNewline` - I've added it to the answer, along with an explanation.