# How to upload files to S3 using the last modified date of a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, scripting

I' am trying to put together a PowerShell script that will allow me to upload files to my AWS S3 Bucket based on the last modified date of a folder.

This is what i have thus far:

```
using namespace System.IO;
Set-AWSCredentials -StoredCredentials MyCredentialsAws
Set-DefaultAWSRegion us-east-1

[String] $root = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestFolder";

[DateTime]$today = [DateTime]::Now.Date;

[FileSystemInfo[]]$folderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Directory;
foreach( $folder in $folderList ) {

    if( $folder.LastWriteTime -lt $today ) {
        [String] $folderPath = $folder.FullName;
        aws s3 cp $folder s3://bucketname/$folder --recursive 
   }
}
```

However, the above gives me the error:

> "The User-provided path does not exist"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The message looks like it comes from the `aws` command. Try `$name = $folder.Name; aws s3 cp $folderPath s3://bucketname/$name --recursive`.

Comment: That fixed it!!! You're a god mate @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you used `$folder` as the source in the `aws` commandline when you probably intended to use `$folderPath`. Also, the expansion of `Get-ChildItem` is not consistent. Depending on the context the objects are sometimes expanded to just the name, and sometime to the full path ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/1630171) for a more detailed explanation). Because of that it's considered good practice to explicitly use the property needed for the given scenario (`Name`, `FullName`, ...).

```
if ($folder.LastWriteTime -lt $today) {
    $folderPath = $folder.FullName
    $folderName = $folder.Name
    aws s3 cp $folderPath s3://bucketname/$folderName --recursive 
}
```