# Need to list all new files in directory with Powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have to create a list of all latest or accessed files in a directory in .csv format. However my current script doesn't output a useful file. (always 0KB)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path X:\ -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_.Name -Recurse | 
select Name, *time | 
Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1 } |
Export-Csv -Path C:\...\testfile.csv
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

EDIT: The errors look like this:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (X:\xxx:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: It works only a bit for me unfortunately, after like 5mins i get some "Path too long"-Errors :/

Comment: @drgreenthumb93 Please add this information directly to your question.

Answer (score 1):

That code might generate some errors if you don't `cd` to `X:\` before running it. You can remediate that with changing:

```
# this
Get-ChildItem $_.Name -Recurse
# to this
Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse
```

Then it always uses absolute path rather than relative one.

---

**NOTE**: as [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) pointed out in the comments, it's worth noting that in PowerShell 6 and higher the same can be achieved by using the object directly (no need to use `.FullName` property).

Here's his [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) explaining it in details - really worth reading!

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this!

Comment: @drgreenthumb93 sure, once you test either please [mark answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or add the details of what doesn't work to **your question**.

Comment: @drgreenthumb93 has since stated in a comment that the actual problem is the occurrence of "Path too long" errors.