# Powershell Get-Item / Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

Quite new to Powershell and scripting/programming and have a pretty basic problem I'm stuck with.

If I have a structure such as this:

[image: File stucture piccy]

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
```

And do the following, I get the folders within the Logfiles folder:

```
 $folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path .\Logfiles -Recurse
```

If I then do the following I can see the first subfolder in "Logfiles"

```
$folders[0]
```

But now if I do the following, it seems to be using the "Scripts" folder instead of "Logfiles" as a root folder:

```
Get-ChildItem $folders[0]
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem .\Logfiles\$folders[0]
```

...(gives a null result)

Does anyone have any information on how directories work within powershell commands? I'm guessing I'm making a very basic mistake with handling the commands!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell takes `$folders[0]` - which resolves to a `[DirectoryInfo]` object - and attempts to convert it to a *string* that it can bind to `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Path` parameter.

But converting the directory object to a string results in just its *name*, the information about its location gets lost in the process.

Instead, you'll want to either do:

```
$folders[0] |Get-ChildItem
```

... which will cause PowerShell to correctly bind the full path of the directory object - or you can pass the full path as the argument to `-Path`:

```
Get-ChildItem $folders[0].FullName
```

Comment: Cheers for the explanation Mathias, still getting to grips with structuring commands in Powershell.  

Thanks for the the reputation bump too!

Comment: The learning curve is a bit steep, thankfully the feedback loop is tight :)

Comment: Note that in PowerShel [Core] v6.1+ `$folders[0]`, or, more generally, _all_ objects output by  `Get-ChildItem`, irrespective of what arguments were used, always stringify to their _full path_ (`.FullName`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Get-ChildItem ".\Logfiles\$($folders[0].Name)"
```

Or

```
Get-ChildItem $folders[0].FullName
```

Or my favourite

```
$folders[0] | Get-ChildItem
```