# Rename-item: Cannot rename because item at ... does not exist

Tags: powershell, file-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I am lost with simple rename-item. Need to change names of folders to "01", "02", "03"... Tried everything but at the end I get this "Item doesn't exist". Sorry for dumb question but I am looking for a solution all day.

```
PS C:\Users\admin> 
$nr = 1

Dir E:"Data-test" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘{0}’ -f $nr++)}

Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'ert' does not exist.
At line:3 char:23
+ Dir E:"Data-test" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘{0}’ -f $nr++)}
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
 
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'ukh' does not exist.
At line:3 char:23
+ Dir E:"Data-test" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘{0}’ -f $nr++)}
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
 
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'yph' does not exist.
At line:3 char:23
+ Dir E:"Data-test" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (‘{0}’ -f $nr++)}
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script works fine. (At least the first variation.) You can't run it but once because you rename the file it is working with (i.e. "Data-Test"). I just created a Data-Test file on my E: drive and ran your script without issue once. Then, on second attempt, it couldn't work because it worked the first time.

If you are working with the contents of a directory named "Data-Test," you need to append your $_ with .FullName. (EX: Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ...)

See image:
[image: See image]

If it still doesn't work, ensure that you have a file/folder named "Data-Test" in the CWD of your E: drive. Placing a backslash in the location will guarantee you are working in the root. (EX: E:\Data-Test)

Comment: @user14915444 Indicating the signature is unnecessary since it is only noise, and the web / personal blogs are considered spam (you could put it in your profile but not in the answers)

Comment: +1 for the `$_.FullName` tip, but note that the command in the question (there is only one) does _not_ work fine, because it indeed triggers file-_name_-only stringification. The problem of situational name-only stringification afflicts _Windows PowerShell_, but has been fixed in _PowerShell [Core] v6.1+_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.

Answer (score 3):

[user14915444's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65513163/45375) has provided the crucial pointer:

The problem is that ***Windows PowerShell* situationally stringifies `Get-ChildItem` (`dir`) output objects by file *name* rather than by *full path*, necessitating the use of `$_.FullName`** rather than just `$_`; the **problem has been fixed in *PowerShell [Core] v6.1+*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.

However, in your case the problem can be avoided altogether, by piping the `Get-ChildItem` output *directly* to `Rename-Item`, using a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375), which also speeds up the operation:

```
[ref] $nr = 1
Get-ChildItem E:Data-test | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}' -f $nr.Value++ } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note the use of a [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) variable, which enables incrementing the sequence number across input objects from inside the delay-bind script block. This is necessary, because delay-bind script blocks run in a *child* scope of the caller's scope - unlike the script blocks passed to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (`%`) and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (`?`).
See [GitHub issue #7157](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157) for a discussion of this discrepancy.