# Power Shell script not renaming file with [] characters

Tags: powershell

There are similar questions like this question, example [Rename-item: Cannot rename because item at ... does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512978/rename-item-cannot-rename-because-item-at-does-not-exist) which gives the same error as the one I have.
Mine is specific as the script works for some files, example

NB. I am not advanced in powershell scripting

| Files | Renamed |
| --- | --- |
| DbBackUpV4.bak | true |
| LongNameUpTo50Chars.bak | true |
| Db[BackUp]V4.bak | false |
| AnyNameWithChars[].bak | false |

the database backup files are named differently, I just noticed that the ones with `[]` charaters generate the error `Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '' does not exist.`
out of curiosity I tried using just one of the characters `[` and I got another type of error `Message:"Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: DbBackUp[be9e-Full.bak"`

I also check for windows file naming rules the characters `[]` are used for file naming, which makes me conclude it has to be something with power shell scripting.

```
$Now = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyyhhmmss"
$NewFileName = $FileNameWithoutExtensionShort + "_DWArchive_" + $Now + $num + $BackupFileExtention;
$num = $num + 1; 

if ($NewFileName.Contains("[") -or $NewFileName.Contains("]") -or $NewFileName.Contains("-")) {
  #Remove special characters from name before renaming
  Log -Message "Remove special characters from name ($NewFileName) before renaming"
  $NewFileName = $NewFileName.replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_").replace("-", "_")
}
# if($_.Exists){
#   Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName  $NewFileName. #This also fails
# }
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName  $NewFileName
```

This is the part of the script, it is inside a loop, and $_.FullName gives me the name of the original file.

What exactly am I missing? Thanks for helping

Comment: Try `Rename-Item -LiteralPath` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-LiteralPath` argument. instead.

> LiteralPath
>
> Specifies a path to one or more locations. The value of LiteralPath is
> used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as
> wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in
> single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell PowerShell not to
> interpret any characters as escape sequences.

`-Path` with parse some special characters so the use of  `?`, `*` `[` and `]` might get problematic.

References:

[About wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2)

[Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2)