# Get-Item : Cannot find path because it does not exist when piped from Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

When running the following Powershell snippet, I get the error **Get-Item : Cannot find path '*path*' because it does not exist.** even though the *path* in question does exist. As far as I can tell, it only seems to fail when there are two `Get-ChildItem` piped together.

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem | % { Get-Item $_ }
```

The following three snippets do work however.

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem | Get-Item
Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem | Get-Item | % { Get-Item $_} 
Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem | % { Get-Item $_.FullName }
```

Both `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Item` return seem to be returning the same object.  What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that _Windows PowerShell_ situationally stringifies `Get-ChildItem` output objects by file _name_ rather than by full path; the problem has been fixed in _PowerShell [Core] v6.1+_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for details.