# PowerShell is not returning correct value when using Measure-Object to find a size of a Directory

Tags: powershell, file, directory

[image]I have a bunch of folders sitting out on a couple of servers. I'm trying to clean them up to free up disk space. I'm trying to find directories that haven't been touched in 7 years or more. Since the folder structure is set up a certain way, I want to display folders by Name, Size, and Last Write Time. So far I have this code.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $HDriveServer1 -Depth 1 -Directory -Force | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddYears(-7)} | Select-Object Name,@{Name='Size';Exp={(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB}},LastWriteTime | Out-File $report
```

The name and last time written seem to output correctly, however the size all show the same values. This is the output I am seeing and can't figure out why the size is the same.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Output of code

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` inside of your calculated property is never given an explicit path. Therefore it takes the current directory (the one where the script is called) every time it is executed. So it is always the same path. Try `Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -File -Force`

Comment: That makes sense and was a facepalm moment... Unfortunately, that changed the values in the Size column to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) points out, **the `Get-ChildItem` call nested in your [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) (`@{Name=...}`) lacks an input path** and therefore operates on the *current* directory rather than the one specified by the pipeline input object.

The robust way to provide this input directory, which is reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), to the nested `Get-ChildItem` call via the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $HDriveServer1 -Depth 1 -Directory -Force | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddYears(-7)} | 
    Select-Object Name,
                  @{
                    Name = 'Size'
                    Expression = {
                      ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1MB
                    }
                  },
                  LastWriteTime |
     Out-File $report
```

While you would *expect* `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_` to be equivalent to
`$_ | Get-ChildItem`, in *Windows PowerShell* it *situationally* isn't, because `$_` is *stringified* as an argument, and sometimes stringifies to its file *name* only, not the *full path*.

An alternative is to use `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName`.

This problem has been corrected in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for more information.