# How to pass an array to the arguments in Start-Process in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to play certain files in a player. I use Get-ChildItem to get an array of file names. Then I want to use Start-Process to play these files. However, how can I add these file names to the arguments of the player program?

I used `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe" -ArgumentList $selected_items` but it seems it doesn't work and the files are not played.

Notice there are spaces in the file names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Syntax*-wise, your approach *should* work, but *doesn't*, due to an unfortunate *bug*, still present in PowerShell 7.2** - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

- While passing an *array* of arguments to [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s `-ArgumentList` parameter does cause the array elements to be passed as *individual arguments* (which is usually how external CLIs expect multiple file arguments), **the necessary double-quoting around elements *with spaces* is *not* applied** when the command line ultimately used for invocation is constructed behind the scenes.
- Also, for robustness you should **use the `.FullName` property** of the objects stored in `$selected_items`, so as to ensure that *full paths* are passed, because - in *Windows PowerShell*, situationally - `Get-ChildItem`'s output objects may stringify to the file *name* only - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

**Workaround**: **Pass a *single* argument to `-ArgumentList`**, in which you **encode *all* pass-through arguments**, using ***embedded double-quoting***.

```
Start-Process `
  -FilePath "C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe" `
  -ArgumentList ($selected_items.ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f $_.FullName }) -join ' ')
```

Taking a step back:

**If `PotPlayerMini64.exe` is a Windows *GUI*(-subsystem) application, you don't need `Start-Process` at all**, because even direct invocation will then act *asynchronously* (i.e., the program will launch, and control will return to PowerShell right away; conversely, if you wanted to *wait for the program to exit*, use `Start-Process -Wait`).

```
& "C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe" $selected_Items.FullName
```

Note that in direct invocations such as this, PowerShell *does* perform the necessary double-quoting behind the scenes, on demand.

Note: I'm unclear on whether passing multiple file paths to `PotPlayerMini64.exe` *alone* also *starts playback* - the alternative solution in the next section may ensure that.

---

**Alternative, clipboard-based solution**:

Judging by `PotPlayerMini64.exe`'s [available command-line options](https://github.com/red217/EmbyExternalPlayerLauncher/issues/2)<sup>[1]</sup>, the following *may* work (I cannot personally verify):

> `/clipboard` :Appends content(s) from clipboard into playlist and starts playback immediately.

```
# Copy the full names of the files of interest to the clipboard.
Set-Clipboard -Value $selected_items.FullName

# Launch the player and tell it to start playback of the files on the clipboard.
# Parameters -FilePath and -ArgumentList are positionally implied.
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe' /clipboard
```

There are file-arguments-related options such as `/new`, `/insert`, and `/add`, but it's unclear to me whether they - or omitting them altogether, as in your attempt - automatically *start playback* (may depend on the application's persistent configuration).

---

<sup>[1] Note that this is not the official documentation; I couldn't find the latter.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Get-ChildItem . | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe" -ArgumentList $_.FullName}
```

Comment: @dspjm yeah, why on earth would someone listen to multiple audio files at the same time?

Comment: The typical use case is to submit multiple files _as a playlist_, and then play one after the other. [`PotPlayerMini64.exe`'s command-line syntax](https://github.com/red217/EmbyExternalPlayerLauncher/issues/2) is undoubtedly capable of receiving multiple files as arguments.

Comment: @mklement0 how can you say "undoubtedly", when in your answer you say "may work" ?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said its undoubtedly _designed_ to accept multiple files, based on its command-line syntax (assuming the source is authoritative - it's the best I could find - do tell us if you know a better one). The _may_ in my answer comes from my inability to try the command _myself_. But if you do have access to `PotPlayerMini64.exe`, do try it, and please report back.

Comment: And, to recapitulate what the question asks for: (a) pass _multiple_ files and (b) start playback.

Comment: I also forgot that `-ArgumentList`  is buggy with respect to arguments _with spaces_ (as stipulated in the question), so `-ArgumentList $_.FullName` won't work. (I've amended my answer).

Comment: @mklement0 Although theoretically the files are invoked sequentially, the program does add the files to the playlist, therefore it works in the Potplayer's case. Anyway, the method in your edited answer seems better. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need start-process (plus, -argumentlist doesn't handle filenames with spaces as easily).

```
& "C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe" 
C:\Program` Files\DAUM\PotPlayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files\DAUM\PotPlayer'; PotPlayerMini64
```

Even using start-process, it varies with the program.  For example, Emacs can take multiple file arguments, separated by spaces.  If the filename has a space, it would need to be double quoted.  External programs don't know what arrays are, and start-process converts them to one string with spaces in between each element.

```
start emacs file1,file2,'"my file"'

get-wmiobject win32_process | ? name -eq emacs.exe | % commandline
"c:\program files\emacs\bin\emacs.exe" file1 file2 "my file"

ps emacs | % commandline  # ps 7
"c:\program files\emacs\bin\emacs.exe" file1 file2 "my file"
```

Comment: What about his actual question?(;