# PowerShell: Error while using Get-ChildItem with '-Filter'

Tags: powershell, filter, include, get-childitem

The following code is part of my script to filter txt files > 0 KB and send them by e-mail as attachments.

```
$file_path = "\\path\to\my\files"
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $file_path -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse | where-object {$_.Length -gt 0} | sort-object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

I 've got the following files inside my folder `$file_path`: `test.txt | dummy1.txt | order.txt`
The result of `$file` is an `array` and I attache each single file to an e-mail and send it by using `Send-MailMessage -To $_to -Subject $_subject -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -Body $_body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $_server -From $_from -Attachments $_attachments`. This leads to an error, that the file could not be found.

```
Send-MailMessage : The "C:\WINDOWS\system32\test.txt" could not be found.
```

I don't understand, why the error comes? I mean, I defined the correct path in `$file_path = "\\path\to\my\files"` but the error messages shows a way different path `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`.
If I use `-Include` instead of `-Filter` it works and my e-mail with the attached files will be send correctly without any issues. Why does `-Filter` leads to an error?

Comment: `-Attachments $_attachments.FullName` <-- make sure you pass the rooted path of the file to `-Attachments`

Comment: Also note that the problem, as described in Mathias' answer, only surfaces in _Windows PowerShell_, and there only _situationally_. In _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances that `Get-ChildItem` outputs now _consistently_ stringify to their full path. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The `-Attachments` parameter expects *string* arguments (the path(s) to the attachment(s)), but Windows PowerShell unfortunately converts the file info object to its name, "filename.txt". PowerShell then interprets the argument as a path relative to the current folder (eg. `C:\Windows\System32`), and you receive the error because that's not actually the location of the file.

To explicitly pass the rooted file path rather than just the file name, use the `FullName` property:

```
Send-MailMessage ... -Attachments $_attachments.FullName
```