# Searching for only folders that contain a certain folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to use powershell to update some programs for my company. I am writing a script to do so (as instructed). When I install the new version of the program on the machines, it also requires me to 'upgrade' existing folders to match the new version of the software.
I need to find all of the folders that contain a certain hidden folder(let the name of said folder be .blah). I am trying to use the get-childitem command, with -path [drives to check] -Recurse -Directory -Force -EA SilentlyContinue. However, I am not sure how to filter correctly to only find folders that contain the .blah folder inside of it.
Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: seems like `-Filter *blah` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call with a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call that tests for a child directory of a given name using [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path):

```bash
# Note: "." refers to the *current* directory
#       Adjust as needed.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath . -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction Ignore |
  Where-Object {
    Test-Path -ItemType Container -LiteralPath "$($_.FullName)\.blah" 
  }
```

- The `Get-ChildItem` call outputs all directories (`-Directory`) in the entire directory subtree (`-Recurse`), including *hidden* ones (`-Force`), ignoring any errors (such as from lack of permissions, `-ErrorAction Ignore`).
- The `Where-Object` call calls `Test-Path` to look for a `.blah` child directory (`-ItemType Container`) in the directory at hand (`$_`).

  - With a `-LiteralPath` argument, `Test-Path` finds the specified path if it exists, irrespective of whether the target file or directory is *hidden*.

    - By contrast, with a *wildcard*-based `-Path` argument, hidden items are *not* found, and given that, as of PowerShell 7.2.5, `Test-Path` has *no* `-Force` switch, there is no way to force their inclusion; this gap in functionality is the subject of [GitHub issue #6501](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6501).
  - Note: In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you could simplify `"$($_.FullName)\.blah"` to `"$_\.blah"`, because the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` and `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances output by `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Item` there *consistently* stringify to their *full path* (`.FullName`) property, unlike in *WindowsPowerShell*, where they *situationally* stringify by their file/directory *name* only - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).