# Issue with code in VS Code vs Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-ise, powershell-core

I have been trying to figure out why a script is working in Powershell ISE and not in VS Code.  The script compares contents of the User folder and compares those folders with a partial name match to csv files in a logs folder.  The exports those results to a CSV file.  The code doesn't work with the export pipe or without it.  The ISE shows results expected but when put through VS Code the results are nowhere to be seen.  Same code, same comments, same everything.

Code follows:

```
# C:\Logs and C:\Users arrays #

$Logs = Get-ChildItem \\computername\c$\Logs\*.csv
$User = Get-ChildItem \\computername\c$\Users

# Comparison of C:\Users with partial name match of files in C:\Logs #

 $Results =  Foreach ($Line in $User) {
                Foreach ($Line2 in $Logs) {
                   if ($Line2 -like "*${Line}*") {$Line2} 
    }
  }
 $Results | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime | Sort-Object {$_.LastWritetime} -Descending #| Export-Csv -Path "C:\Install\ProfileDate.csv"
```

I've wracked my brain on this and I am convinced it's something simple that I'm just blanking on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Ran the same code through ISE and VS Code.

Comment: My guess is because you are trying to query a remote computer. What happens if you replace `\\computername\c$` with `C:`, i.e. run it on the local host. For connecting to a remote machine from VS Code, maybe [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) will help?

Comment: What is returned what you run `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: Replacing remote computer with local C: has the same result.

Comment: Psversiontable from VS Code gives 7.4.1

Comment: Yea, I used it only as a test since VS Code was refusing to work, good to have multiple test points in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface:**

- The issue **comes down to the differences between *Windows PowerShell*** (the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with Windows edition) **and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition), as detailed below.
  As such, the execution environments (ISE vs. Visual Studio Code) are incidental to the problem.
- While **these two PowerShell editions are *largely* compatible**, there are [**unavoidable differences**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell), and their number will grow over time, given that only PowerShell 7+ is still actively developed.

---

Even though you've named your iteration variables `$Line` and `$Line2`, they do not contain *lines*, but [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances, as emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

As such, you're relying on their *implicit stringification* in your [`-like` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like), and the problem is that the stringification behavior of these types *changed* between *Windows PowerShell* (the only edition supported in the obsolescent<sup>[1]</sup> ISE) and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (which you happen to be running in Visual Studio Code):

- In short: **In *Windows PowerShell*, `Get-ChildItem` output *situationally* stringifies to the file/directory *name only*, whereas in *PowerShell 7+* it always stringifies to the *full paths***.
- The `Get-ChildItem` calls in your question happen to produce name-only stringification in Windows PowerShell; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for background information.

Therefore, to make your code work in PowerShell 7+ and exhibit the same behavior you saw in Windows PowerShell, you must explicitly refer to the `.Name` property of the objects output by `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$Results = foreach ($dir in $User) {
  foreach ($file in $Logs) {
    if ($file.Name -like "*$($dir.Name)*") { $file } 
  }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] The Windows PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).</sup>