# Powershell: passing a wildcard as a filename to an external command

Tags: windows, powershell, adb

I am trying to use the 'adb' binary to copy a bunch of files from an Android device - all from a PowerShell prompt running under Windows 11.

The Android device contains a bunch of files in its removable media ( '/sdcard/' ):

```
.\adb.exe ls /sdcard/
000045f8 00002000 65e1f6f0 .
000045f8 00001000 65d5165c ..
000081b0 00006374 65e1f65e a.json
000081b0 00003234 65e1f660 b.json
000081b0 00003adf 65e1f662 c.json
000081b0 000048de 65e1f664 d.json
000081b0 00003f5d 65e1f66d e.json
(...)
```

Copying one of them is not a problem:

```
.\adb.exe pull /sdcard/a.json
/sdcard/a.json: 1 file pulled, 0 skipped. 1.6 MB/s (11118 bytes in 0.006s)
```

How do I copy all of them in one go though? (there are hundreds) This:

```
.\adb.exe pull /sdcard/*.json
adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/sdcard/*.json': No such file or directory
```

doesn't seem to work.

I am able to do this from MacOS and Linux - by passing the wildcard just like in the command above. Windows 11 however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer.

ADB does not interpret the '*' the way you think it does.

```
.\adb.exe pull /sdcard/.
```

I do not know of a way to copy just .json files.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/sdcard/.` in lieu of `/sdcard/*.json`, as shown in [JohnneyDarkness's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78089223/45375), may work *situationally*, namely:

- (a) if the target executable happens to understand *directory* paths to mean: process all files in that directory - this *is* the case with `adb`
- (b) if the directory contains *only* files of interest and - as in the case of `adb`  - copying the entire *directory tree* is desired/acceptable.

That said, if these criteria are met, this is undoubtedly the best and most efficient solution.

---

**To address the question more generally**:

- The use of [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb) is an interesting case, because the globbing (aka [filename/pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)) must happen in the *Android device's* rather than in the *caller's* file-system.

  - Therefore:

    - Unlike what you state, I think that `adb pull /sdcard/*.json` would *not* work on *macOS* and *Linux*, because PowerShell would indeed attempt the globbing in the caller's file-system. (PowerShell does so in an attempt to *emulate* the globbing behavior of POSIX-compatible shells on these platforms, and only does so when calling *external programs*).
    - On *Windows*, PowerShell fundamentally performs *no* globbing - it is up to each target program to do so (Windows has no history of globbing as a *shell* feature).

      - As an aside: **To *generally emulate globbing on Windows*** (in the caller's file-system), you would use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item); [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) works too and gives you more flexibility, but the caveat in *Windows PowerShell* (no longer in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) is that its output [situationally stringifies to mere file *names*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375), in which case `(Get-ChildItem ...).FullName` must be used. For instance, the following command passes the full paths of all `*.txt` files in the current directory to the target program  as *individual arguments*; `cmd.exe` is used as the sample target program, and `/c echo` simply makes it echo all arguments, separated with a single space each:

        ```
        # This is the Windows equivalent of `/bin/echo *.txt` on Unix,
        # except that *full* paths are passed.
        cmd /c echo (Get-Item *.txt)
        ```
  - More fundamentally, however, `adb pull` seemingly only accepts only *one* file or directory name at a time.
- Therefore:

  - You need a separate `adb` call that uses globbing *on the Android side* to identify the files of interest, which you can do via `adb shell`
  - You can then iterate over the resulting file paths via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and call `adb pull` on each.

```
# PowerShell command that should work on all platforms.
./adb shell 'ls /sdcard/*.json' | ForEach-Object { ./adb pull $_ }
```